# split text by any first item matched from a list

Tags: python, list, parsing

I am looking for an elegant way to find the first match from a list of  prepositions in a text so that I can parse a text like "Add shoes behind the window", the result should be ["shoes","behind the window"]

It works as long as there are not multiple prepositions in the text

> my keys behind the window **before**:  my keys  **after**:  behind the
>   window
>
> my keys under the table in the kitchen **before**:  my keys under
>   the table  **after**:  in the kitchen
>
> my keys in the box under the table in the kitchen **before**:  my
>   keys  **after**:  in the box under the table in the kitchen

In the 2nd example, the result should be ["my keys","under the table in the kitchen"]

Whats an elegant way to find the first match of any of the words in the list?

```
def get_text_after_preposition_of_place(text):
    """Returns the texts before[0] and after[1] <preposition of place>"""

prepositions_of_place = ["in front of","behind","in","on","under","near","next to","between","below","above","close to","beside"]
    textres = ["",""]

    for key in prepositions_of_place:
        if textres[0] == "":
            if key in text:
                textres[0] = text.split(key, 1)[0].strip()
                textres[1] = key + " " + text.split(key, 1)[1].strip()
    return textres
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

def get_text_after_preposition_of_place(text):
    """Returns the texts before[0] and after[1] <preposition of place>"""

    prepositions_of_place = ["in front of","behind","in","on","under","near","next to","between","below","above","close to","beside"]
     preps_re = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(prepositions_of_place) + r')\b')

    split = preps_re.split(text, maxsplit=1)
    return split[0], split[1]+split[2]

print(get_text_after_preposition_of_place('The cat in the box on the table'))  
# ('The cat ', 'in the box on the table')
```

First, we create a regex that will look like `(in|on|under)`. Note the parentheses: they will allow us to capture the strings on which we split the string in order to keep them in the output.

Then, we split, allowing 1 split at most, and concatenate the last two parts: the preposition and the rest of the string.

Comment: You want to add `\b` before and after the regular expression to ensure you don't match `in` and `on` in the middle of words.

Comment: Thank you @G.Sliepen, I had forgotten about that, I edited the answer!